# Is there a way to get a non-null Principal/Authentication using Spring Security with anonymous access?

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security, and want to be able to run with a "local" profile with security off. I can do this by using a profile-controlled `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which allows anonymous access, but the problem is that any `Principal` or `Authentication` arguments to controller methods are null.

The way I've solved this before is by passing the arguments through an adapter, which has a non-local pass-through implementation and a "local"-profile implementation that substitutes a configured value:

```java
    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<List<Thing>> getThings(Principal principal) {

        Principal myPrincipal = securityAdapter.principal(principal);

        ...
    }
```

But this feels really clunky. Is there some way to configure Spring Security to make the substitution so that I can keep the code clean?

Comment: What do you mean by "security off*? If you just allow anonymous access, the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter should have stored an AnonymousAuthenticationToken in the SecurityContextHolder, and you should get it as an Authentication parameter in controller methods.

Comment: Yes, anonymous access is what I have with my local profile. As you say, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() gets me a principal named "anonymousUser", but the Principal and/or Authentication args in the controller method are null.

SecurityContextHolder's static getContext isn't unit-test friendly - but wrapping it a mockable context provider is arguably neater than the adapter solution in my OP, which aims to use the convenience of the method arguments but then has to do some clunky pre-processing on it. So it's probably the lesser of the two clunks...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is a SpringSecurity *feature*: the AnonymousAuthenticationToken is not injected in controller methods. I could find some references for that in this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4011).

A possible workaround (from above issue) is to inject a custom trust resolver that pretends that the AnonymousAuthenticationToken is not anonymous...

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver() {
    return new AuthenticationTrustResolver() {

        @Override
        public boolean isRememberMe(final Authentication authentication) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAnonymous(final Authentication authentication) {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Rather ugly, but as it is intended to run in a profile where anonymous authentication is expected to be valid, it could be enough.